# arc land "Not possible to fast-forward, aborting."

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

i am trying to land my arc patch. I am up-to-date with origin/master, my patch was reviewed and accepted. On teh phabricator site is says: `Next Step arc land 'arcpatch-D37'`.
But if i use `arc patch D37` and then `arc land` i run into problems.

It breaks at the pull:

```
Switched back to branch ←[1marcpatch-D37←[m.

[2014-04-29 14:06:50] EXCEPTION: (CommandException) Command failed with error #1
28!
COMMAND
git pull --ff-only --no-stat

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
at [D:\arcanist\libphutil\src\future\exec\ExecFuture.php:398]
```

I tried pulling first and had no problems/conflicts.
No idea what to do/try next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

1. `git stash` (make sure it's your only stash via `git stash list`)
2. `git checkout master` (switch to your `master` branch)
3. `git branch -D arcpatch-D37` (delete the old branch)
4. `git reset --hard origin/master` (reset your current branch)
5. `git pull` (update the master branch)
6. `arc patch D37` (create a fresh branch)
7. `arc land` (land it!)

Comment: Still using this every time i land :D

Comment: You don't have to do this every time, you faced the issue because you had some local commits in master branch. If you set a habit of working on local dev branches and keep master branch always clean and updated, arc land will run cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Our team started working on a new feature branch and ran into this same error trying to land diffs. The fix for us was to ensure that the feature branch's upstream was set correctly.

1. `git checkout <branch>`
2. `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch>`
3. Go back to your patch or working branch and `arc land`